# C++ Compilation Error: ":-1: error: error: /INCREMENTAL:NO: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, incremental-compiler

When I tried to compile my project using QT creator, it gave me the error message:

":-1: error: error: /INCREMENTAL:NO: No such file or directory"

I'm fairly new to C++, so I don't know much about it other than what I have found on Google.

I've obviously spent a while searching, but I can't find anything close to my error message. I don't understand it at all either, and even if you could point me in the right direction to finding out by myself that would be amazingly helpful.

I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the PC I am using, but I won't be able to check with another PC until later this evening.
I'll refrain from posting my code as it's a large project and I'm not usre if the code itself is relevant. If it is then, again, pointing me in the direction to solving it myself will be fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us where you disable incremental linking in your `.pro` file.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass Visual C++ options to some other compiler.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks guys, I had no idea what to do. I'm a little impressed that you knew exactly what to do.